# Custom taxonomy archive list - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, archive, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I want to display a custom taxonomy page.

```
    $microblogging_taxonomy_slug="theme";
    $microblogging_taxonomy_singular="theme";
    $microblogging_taxonomy_plural="themes"

    $labels = array(
        'name'              => $microblogging_taxonomy_plural,
        'singular_name'     => $microblogging_taxonomy_singular,
        'search_items'      => sprintf( __( 'Search %s',LANGUAGE_MICROBLOGGING ), strtolower($microblogging_taxonomy_plural) ),
        'all_items'         => sprintf( __( 'All %s',LANGUAGE_MICROBLOGGING ), strtolower($microblogging_taxonomy_plural) ),
        'parent_item'       => sprintf( __( 'Parent %s',LANGUAGE_MICROBLOGGING ), strtolower($microblogging_taxonomy_singular) ),
        'parent_item_colon' => sprintf( __( 'Parent %s :',LANGUAGE_MICROBLOGGING ), strtolower($microblogging_taxonomy_singular) ),
        'edit_item'         => sprintf( __( 'Edit %s',LANGUAGE_MICROBLOGGING ), strtolower($microblogging_taxonomy_singular) ),
        'update_item'       => sprintf( __( 'Update %s',LANGUAGE_MICROBLOGGING ), strtolower($microblogging_taxonomy_singular) ),
        'add_new_item'      => sprintf( __( 'Add new %s',LANGUAGE_MICROBLOGGING ), strtolower($microblogging_taxonomy_singular) ),
        'new_item_name'     => sprintf( __( 'New %s',LANGUAGE_MICROBLOGGING ), strtolower($microblogging_taxonomy_singular) ),
        'menu_name'         => $microblogging_taxonomy_plural,
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => false,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => $microblogging_taxonomy_slug ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( MB_CUSTOM_TAX_1_NAME, array( "post" ), $args );
```

now I want to create a template for this page "mysite.dev/theme/". Is it possible?

I create this taxonomy with a plugin and so I would use a filter like

```
add_filter( 'taxonomy_template', 'mb_get_custom_taxonomy_template' );
```

For example I use a function, attached to the 'archive_template' filter hook, to replace tax original theme template

```
 function mb_get_custom_post_type_template_archive($archive_template)   {
     global $taxonomy,$term,$wp_query;
     global $mb_css_js_version;

     if (is_tax() && $taxonomy == MB_CUSTOM_TAX_1_NAME) {

        $archive_template = MB_TEMPLATE_CUSTOM_TAX_1_DIR . "index.php";

     }
     else if (is_post_type_archive(MB_POST_TYPE)) {

        $archive_template = MB_TEMPLATE_ARCHIVE_DIR . "post_type_archive/index.php";
     }
     return $archive_template;
}
```

With this function I can view my plugin template

ex. mysite.dev/theme/theme-1 mysite.dev/theme/theme-2

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39500/how-to-create-a-permalink-structure-with-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-post-types Hope it helps you.

Comment: it was helpful! Thank u!
I created a custom page and I used add_rewrite_rule ;)